# Oracle query group by

Tags: oracle, group-by, max, having

I need to get 1 row back with sum of some values by max date. But these 2 rows were updated by different persons, but only need to show the latest updated by person id.

My query is:

```
select v.code, sum(v.a_lines), sum(v.b_lines),
v.updated_by, f.period, max(v.updated_on)
from f_values v, f_file f where 
v.file_id = f.id
and v.code= '100002'
and 
to_char(f.period,'MM/DD/YYYY') = '03/31/2011'
group by v.code, v.updated_by, f.period
```

This returns 2 rows:

```
102 30  100 xxx 31-MAR-11   10-AUG-11
102 50  200 yyy 31-MAR-11   07-OCT-11
```

Now we need to return only 1 row. Something like this:

```
102   80   3000   yyy 31-Mar-11  07-Oct-11
```

I know that this can be achieved by removing "updated_by" from the column, but I need to have it populated, but it only needs to be the most recent updated_by row ('yyy'). Hope my question is clear

Please let know if this is possible. Thanks in advance

Harish

Comment: This works: MAX(updated_by) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY updated_on DESC)! BUT hibernate HQL doesn't work :(. Anyone please

Comment: Unexpected token KEEP is the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by using

```
MAX(updated_by) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY updated_on DESC)
```

But this query does not work on HQL, so had to change to SQL query. If anyone can help on the HQL equivalent, that would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the most recent updated_by row. It seems a little too obvious, but wouldn't `MIN(v.updated_by)` and removing `v.updated_by` from the `GROUP BY` clause do what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried that too. "updated_by" is the user_id. So max or min doesn't work as expected. I want the updated_by id of the most recent one. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: In the above example, I want the updated_by id of the most recent updated_on date. So that would be 'yyy' in this case

Comment: Got it to work by using MAX(updated_by) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY updated_on DESC)! :)